# Meteor: onhashchange does not fire

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a weird situation. It seems Meteor with Iron::Router is overriding somewhere the onhashchange event however I was unsuccessfully to track it down.

Basically if I listen for that event, it never fires for some reason. I looked and searched everywhere and can not even find any reference to onhashchange in the Meteor code base.

```
if(Meteor.isClient) {
  window.addEventListener('hashchange', function() {
    alert('changed');
  });
}
```

This never fires - although the event is properly registered. In plain vanilla it works fine .. so I assume it's somewhere being overwritten.. any insights will be appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/L2dj3o7n/

Oh one more thing, this is how my URL's look like right now for testing:

```
http://localhost:3000/#/workflow
http://localhost:3000/#/settings/account
http://localhost:3000/#/group/add
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

From the Router Parameters section of the [Iron Router guide](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#route-parameters):

> If there is a query string or hash fragment in the url, you can access
>   those using the query and hash properties of the this.params object.
>
> ```
> // given the url: "/post/5?q=s#hashFrag" 
> Router.route('/post/:_id',
> function () {   
>     var id = this.params._id;   
>     var query = this.params.query; // query.q -> "s"   
>     var hash = this.params.hash; // "hashFrag" 
> });
> ```
>
> Note: If you want to rerun a function when the hash changes you can do
>   this:
>
> ```
> // get a handle for the controller. 
> // in a template helper this would be 
> // var controller = Iron.controller(); 
> var controller = this;
>
> // reactive getParams method which will invalidate the comp if any part of the params change 
> // including the hash. 
> var params = controller.getParams();
> ```

getParams is reactive, so if the hash updates, the getParams() call should invalidate and trigger a new computation for whatever you're using it for.  For instance, if you wanted to dynamically render a template depending on the hash value, you should be able to do something like this...
HTML:

```
<template name='myTemplate'>
  {{> Template.dynamic template=getTemplateFromHash}}
</template>
```

JS:

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  getTemplateFromHash: function() { 
    var hash = Iron.controller().getParams().hash;
    ... // do whatever you need to do with the hash to figure out the template to render
  }
});
```